# Recreating UI scrolling like in google+

Tags: android, scroll

I like how the scrolling in the google+ app is where text of what screen you are on moves when you scroll left to right

[image]

[image: scrolling]

in the second image I scroll to the left and the text of that section moves with it.

How can I recreate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the new ViewPager component: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html